# php: count number of times a string appears in an mySql array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

*** edit ***
I asked this question as a php question, without the tag of mySql (which has been added by another SO member --> not a big deal to me, but just saying). I am sorry for any confusion the inclusion of the ?extraneous? detail that the array was from a mySql query!

I am hoping to *keep the queried data from the `SELECT *` to loop through using PHP in an array*. I thought, in order to keep this code simple, that PHP could count the number of times a string occurs in a particular position in an array.
*** /edit ***

I would like to find out how many times a string appears in a particular column from a mySql query result.

For example, lets say I have a table 'automobiles' and their is a column 'type' in that table. The column 'type' has values such as 'sedan', 'van', 'suv' etc.

If I query everything from the table like this:

```
$query = "SELECT *
            FROM automobiles";
```

and then insert the queried values into an array:

```
$the_array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

and then try to quantify the number of times a string occurs like this:

```
$count = array_count_values($the_array);
print_r($count);
```

not only does this not work, but the data would be inaccurate because the values would be based on the entire table, not on the automobile 'type' column alone.

Comment: Hmmm, downvotes for asking easy question?

Comment: @superUntitled Eh, I'd say it belongs here. It's fairly basic, but everyone has to start somewhere...

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I think that I do understand the capabilities of the mySql COUNT() function, as well as the php funtion php_num_rows(). I would like to use all the data in the queried table (hence the 'SELECT *'), as I would like to echo back that data in a `while(){}` loop. I would think that php would be able to count the number of times a string appears in a particular array position.

Comment: whoops, i seem to have asked a question that is outside of the scope of the stack overflow community. How is this question not programming related? It would be nice for downvoters to let me know, so I can better serve this community in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT `type`, COUNT(*) `count` FROM `automobiles` GROUP BY `type`";
```

Comment: thanks for your insite ceejayoz! however, this will only return the COUNTed values, not the rest of the data in the table. My question pertained to the counting of a string within a php array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple SQL aggregation:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*) FROM automobiles GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can go

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM automobiles WHERE type='TYPE'");
$total_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo $total_count;
```

Comment: Not much fun when you have a couple dozen (or million) types.

Comment: then set a variable to only look at one at a time.

Comment: Regarding your now-deleted comment, that wasn't my "childish" downvote.

Comment: i didnt say it was yours as when i posted my comment yours was not there. sorry to make it feel like it was you. my bad.